# Why does the use of traceroute not display the IP address of the route?

Tags: linux, network-interface

My device A uses a Linux customized system and an ARM processor, with two network ports: eth1 (ip: 192.168.1.1) and wlan1 (ip: 192.168.1.6). wlan1 uses a wireless transmitter, so it can be assigned an IP address. I connected wirelessly to wlan1 on computer B and assigned an IP address of 192.168.1.21. Why doesn't 192.168.1.6 appear when I use `traceroute 192.168.1.21`?

```
#traceroute 192.168.1.21
traceroute to 192.168.1.21 (192.168.1.21), 30 hops max, 38 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.21 (192.168.1.21)  2.311 ms  *  3.121 ms
```

Comment: Because it is being bridged, not routed.